# Difference between "will have to" & "would have to"

Tags: meaning, difference

Joey: (picking up a leftover part) What's this?

Chandler: I **would have to** say that is an 'L'-shaped bracket.

Comment: It's related to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/I%27d_say.

Answer (score 0):

'Will have to" is used for making a promise to do something in future.
But 'would have to' has been used here to be more polite to say something.